# How to map line of preprocessed code to its line of C Code

Tags: c, msbuild, c-preprocessor

My program analyzes a **C** program by parsing the preprocessed code. Now I want to get the line number (in **C** Code) of some statements/function calls I found in preprocessed code (I know the line number of preprocessed code). My first idea was to force preprocessor to write corresponding line numbers of **C** code into preprocessed code. Is there any possibility to do so? I didn't find any information about that. I'm using msbuild.

Comment: There should be some [special directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5w2czay.aspx) in the precprocessor output that contains filename and line number information.